# Add empty value to a DropDownList in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm building a data entry interface and have successfully bound the columns that have reference tables for their data using DropDownList so the user selects from the pre-configured values.

My problem now is that I don't want the first value to be selected by default, I need to force the user to select a value from the list to avoid errors where they didn't pick that field and by default a value was assigned.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this than to add code to include an empty value at the top of the list after I get it from the database and before i pass it to the SelectList constructor in my controller class?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The Html helper function takes a 'first empty value' parameter as the third argument.

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("name",dataSource,"-please select item-")%>
```

Comment: Ah this is great, I was looking at `SelectList` object params for this

Answer (score -9):

You can also use this way:

```
dropdownlist.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].Caption;
dropdownlist.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].Caption;
dropdownlist.DataSource = ds;
dropdownlist.DataBind();


dropdownlist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select ...", string.Empty));
```

Comment: I guess the question is regarding asp.net MVC!

Comment: yep, not applicable to asp.net MVC