# ASP.NET MVC Razor: Add empty value to a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I tried for hours to get it work, but now I have to ask..

As read in 
[/942262/add-empty-value-to-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942262/add-empty-value-to-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc) and 
[/3780614/mvc-clear-default-selected-value-of-selectlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780614/mvc-clear-default-selected-value-of-selectlist)

I want to add an empty space to dropdown lists in my ASP.NET MVC Razor WebApp with Entity Framework 5 to force the user for an input.

I followed the informations, but what happend in the View is that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXSgT.png

 So, as you see, there is an empty space, but it isn't selected by default. Instead, my "testproject", as first value from my controller, is marked.. Not the empty space.
So where did I fail? 


Thanks a lot.

My **model** looks like that:

```
    [...]
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class UploadTranferContainer
    {    
         [DisplayName("Project")]
         public int ProjectID { get; set; }

         public SelectList Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

My **controller** fills the data in like:

```
    UploadTranferContainer container = new UploadTranferContainer();
    container.Projects = new SelectList(db.Projects.AsEnumerable(), "ProjectID", "ProjectName");
```

And the **view** unpacks my container like:

```
        <div class="editor-label metadataLabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProjectID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectID, Model.Projects, string.Empty)
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DropdownListFor default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229626/dropdownlistfor-default-value)

Comment: The selected value of the dropdown will be the value (if found) of `Model.ProjectID` in this case. If you want this to appear as the first (empty) option of the select, make sure the value of `ProjectID` is not contained in the select list items `Model.Projects`.

Comment: That should really be an answer, @Jay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selected value of the dropdown will be the value (if found) of `Model.ProjectID`

If you want this to appear as the first (empty) option of the select, make sure the value of `ProjectID` is not contained in the select list items `Model.Projects`

Answer (score 5):

you can use below approach for dropdown with empty values

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProjectID, new SelectList(Model.Projects, "ProjectID", "ProjectName"), " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Allows to create a empty list item

```
var area = new[] { new tbl_Area { AreaID = -1, AreaName = "Please Select Main Area" } };
```

or

```
ViewBag.SubAreaList = new[] { new tbl_Area { AreaID = -1, AreaName = "Please Select Main Area" } };
```

razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("DdlSubAreas", new SelectList(ViewBag.SubAreaList, "AreaID", "AreaName"), new { size = "10" });
```

tbl_Area can be a class or datamodel

```
class tbl_Area{
   public int AreaID {get;set;}
   public string AreaName {get;set;}
}
```